# Problema con file_put_contents en php

Tags: php

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema para editar un archivo .txt mediante el file_put_contents, estoy aprendiendo a hacer un simple panel de control para una pagina,para eso tengo este codigo

````
```

<?php 
if ( isset($_GET['cual']) ) {
$archivo = $_GET['cual'];
$contenido = 
file_get_contents("../Extras/textos/institucional/$archivo.txt");
$solo_lectura = 'readonly';
$boton = 'editar';
}else{
$archivo = 'new';
$contenido = '';
$solo_lectura = '';
$boton = 'crear';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-VEN">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Panel de control</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Panel de control</h1>

<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?cual=Terminos y condiciones">Terminos y 
condiciones</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?cual=Conocenos mas">Conocenos mas</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?cual=Hola mundo">Hola mundo</a></li>
</ul>


<h2>Manejo de textos</h2>

<form method="post" action="acciones/editar_texto.php">
    <input type="text" <?php echo $solo_lectura; ?> name="quien" value="<? 
php echo $archivo; ?>   "/>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $boton ?>" />
        <div> 
        <textarea name="contenido" cols="80" rows="20"><?php echo 
$contenido; ?></textarea>
    </div>
    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```
````

El problema es que cuando intendo editar y guardar cualquiera de mis documentos .txt que vienen por $_GET en el action de mi form,no se editan, lo que  yo hago para guardarlos  es lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
$contenido = $_POST['contenido'];
$archivo = $_POST['quien'];

file_put_contents(
"../../Extras/textos/institucional/$archivo.txt", $contenido);
```

Este es el error que me sale
Warning: file_put_contents(../../Extras/textos/institucional/Conocenos mas .txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\beta\admin\acciones\editar_texto.php on line 6

Lo ultimos de la ruta es el documento que intente editar para hacer el ejemplo.Se que la direccion esta bien porque cuando creo documentos nuevos siempre se guardan en esa ruta especificamente.
La variable $solo_lectura solo influye en el input text pero no en el textarea como uds se podran dar cuenta.
No se si tenga que ver pero el vardump de file_put_contens cuando estoy editando el documento me sale Boolean False, he verificado por var_dump los $_POST y la informacion se envia correctamente el problema es en el file_put...agradeceria su ayuda..y me hagan ver lo que yo no entiendo o no veo gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y cambia las imagenes por texto. Tienes un editor (bastante simple, pero funcional) que ayudará a la gente a hacer pruebas, y a ayudarte mejor

Comment: listo ya editada

Comment: primero de todo, antes del file_put_contents añade un `echo is_writable($file)`, siendo $file la ruta completa que pones en el file_put_contents. Asi veremos si tu aplicacion tiene permisos de escritura en ese directorio, ok?

Comment: Ok @Jakala ya realize la prueba `is_writable` y me salio negativo, al parecer no tengo permisos de escritura. Que puedo hacer ahora?

Comment: quizas me explique mal. el is_writable($file), el $file debe ser solo la ruta, no debe contener el nombre del archivo. lo has probado asi? (solo con la ruta) ?

Comment: Esto es lo que hice para probar  `<?php 
     $file = "../../Extras/textos/institucional/";if (is_writable($file)){
 echo 'el archivo es escribible';
      }else {
 echo 'el archivo no es escribible';
       }`
y ahora me salio que "el archivo es escribible"

Comment: hice el if...para que me imprimiera la respuesta claramente

Comment: que raro... que te da un `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: Buenas disculpa la tardanza ayer me quede dormido...el var dump me arroja esto : array(2) { ["quien"]=> string(14) "Conocenos mas " ["contenido"]

Comment: ¿Tu arhivo se llama `Conocenos mas.txt`?

Comment: Uff. Suena a un problema de espacios en el nombre del archivo. Prueba a escribirlo como "Conocenos_mas" por ej, a ver si te funciona.

Comment: Estuve probando y nada, tambien probe con "ConocenosMas" y tampoco, aunque tambien probe esto : `file_put_contents(
 "../../Extras/textos/institucional/ConocenosMas.txt", $contenido);` escribiendo manualmente el archivo.txt a modificar en vez de usar `$archivo` que trae el `$_POST[quien]` con el nombre del archivo que deseo modificar, si se guardo y edito perfectamente.

Comment: Depure un poco mi prueba con is_writeable..y la ruta es escribible pero cuando agrego $archivo sale no writable